# Benefits of inline functions in templates

Tags: c++, templates, inline

According to the standard, inline definition of a member function in C++ is the same as declaring it with the `inline` keyword. Keeping that in mind, most of the templates I write contain only inline functions, as the code is simply shorter that way (the bodies of the functions would also have to be in the header in order to be usable from multiple `.cpp` files, therefore it would arguably only slow the parsing down).

Does a (sane) compiler now attempt to inline all of the functions? Are there any benefits in defining inline member functions as `inline` in practice (see example below)? Should I avoid writing inline functions even in templates from now on?

```
template <class Foo>
struct Bar {
    inline bool IsThereBenefitInDoingThis()
    {
        return 10 < system("exit `wget -q -o - "
            "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789353/ | grep yes | wc -l`");
    }
};
```

Comment: Any function defined in the class definition is inline, implicitly.

Comment: But of course, you _don't_ want to put the function definitions in the class definitions if you can avoid it.  It practically destroys the readability of the class.  (In most cases, you don't even want them in the same file if you can avoid it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, I'm aware of the practice of putting the function bodies in a `.hpp` file and `#include`ing that in the original header. The question was more about whether the compilers really adhere to the standard in this case.

Comment: Many compilers will perform a cost/benefit analysis of inlining, *maybe* taking into account that the user used `inline`. But `inline` does not force inlining. From the C++11 Standard, [dcl.fct.spec]/3 " The inline
specifier indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call
is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism. An implementation is not required to perform this
inline substitution at the point of call [...]"

Comment: (Stepanov said in one of his lectures that it's still useful to help the compiler in some cases. If in doubt, measure.)

Comment: @dyp Exactly! But at the same time, is the compiler obligated to inline an inline (but not `inline`) function? I think not.

Comment: Not sure what you mean o.O Do you mean a function defined inside the body of a class? Such a function is implicitly `inline` as James Kanze already said. No obligation either for the compiler to *perform inline subsitution at the point of call*.

Comment: @dyp "No obligation either", I like that. So then it still seems like, as you say, "it's still useful to help the compiler in some cases", including the case of the function defined inside a class body. That is the answer to my question.

Comment: @theswine What do you mean, "adhere to the standard"?  `inline` is a recommendation, and a compiler is also allowed to "inline" functions which aren't `inline`.  The only thing required by the standard is that an inline function can be defined in more than one translation unit, and must be defined in all translation units which use it.  (Of course, it would be a very poor compiler which ignores the "hint" implicit in `inline` when optimizing.)

Comment: @JamesKanze It seems (my personal opinion) like the standard is slightly counterintuitive in this case. Defining a function inside the body of a template often takes place in order to simplify one's work (defining it outside of the body is quite verbose, especially if there are many template parameters, also my opinion). Do the compilers really take that as a "hint" to inline it (which they might or might not do), or does it still make sense to declate such functions with `inline`?

Comment: @theswine Compilers treat it exactly as if the function had been declared `inline`.  As for putting the function definitions inside the class definition: it's easier when your writing, but it makes it a lot more difficult to read.  And since code is read a lot more often than it is written...

Comment: @JamesKanze I would accept that as a correct answer, If backed by some kind of proof/evidence.

Comment: [dcl.fct.spec]/3 which describes the `inline` *function-specifier*: "A function defined within a class definition is an inline function." and /4 "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly
the same definition in every case (3.2)." where 3.2 refers to the ODR, which has an explicit exception for inline functions with external linkage. Whether or not the compiler treats this implicit `inline` differently from an explicit `inline` in its cost/benefit analysis, is up to the compiler.

Comment: @dyp I understand the standard. But what do the actual compilers do? There are usually (subtle or not so subtle) differences between what the compilers are supposed to do and what they actually do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple test:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

template <class T>
class Sine {
public:
#ifdef MAKEINLINE
    inline T Eval(T x)
#else // MAKEINLINE
    T Eval(T x)
#endif // MAKEINLINE
#ifdef PUTOUTSIDE
    ;
#else // PUTOUTSIDE
    {
        return T(sin(double(x)));
    }
#endif // PUTOUTSIDE
};

#ifdef PUTOUTSIDE
template <class T>
#ifdef MAKEINLINE
inline T Sine<T>::Eval(T x)
#else // MAKEINLINE
T Sine<T>::Eval(T x)
#endif // MAKEINLINE
{
    return T(sin(double(x)));
}
#endif // PUTOUTSIDE

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    printf("%g\n", Sine<float>().Eval(M_PI));
    printf("%g\n", Sine<double>().Eval(M_PI));
    return 0;
}
```

Running:

```
g++ Main.cpp -o testi -DMAKEINLINE -O1
g++ Main.cpp -o testn -O1
g++ Main.cpp -o testo -DPUTOUTSIDE -O1
g++ Main.cpp -o testoi -DMAKEINLINE -DPUTOUTSIDE -O1
diff testi testn
diff testi testo
diff testi testoi
```

Reveals a difference between `testi` and `testo`, so as long as the body is inside it does not seem to matter whether it is declared `inline`, or at least in this simple case and in g++ (GCC) 4.6.4. Note that increasing optimization level inlines all versions of the function and there are no differences.

Answer (score 1):

You should assume that for optimization purposes compilers ignore the `inline` keyword, and decide what to inline for themselves, and the same rule applies when you use the inline form for class member functions. I don't know exactly which compilers do or don't do this under which conditions, but the standard claim is that it's the general rule, and based on watching videos for compiler courses online I believe it.

However, that doesn't quite mean that either the 'inline' keyword or the inline member function form are useless, or that either have no consequences. The key question is whether it's valid to include the relevant definitions in a header file. Non-inline definitions shouldn't be in a header file - doing so is likely to cause linker errors (duplicate symbols, where the definitions were compiled repeatedly as part of multiple cpp files).

So one form of inline or another is required if you want the definition in the header file (with the consequence being longer compiles, as the definition gets compiled in multiple cpp files with all but one version discarded by the linker).

That said, templates are a bit different again. I forget the details, but I *think* templates are by default treated similarly to `inline` definitions - it's certainly valid (and usually necessary) to define templates completely in header files.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question though, I was asking whether inline `inline` template function (one that is defined in the body and declared `inline` at the same time) makes any difference from the other two ways of writing an inline function.

Comment: @the swine - Yes, sorry, I think no but I don't really know. You're test in your answer is (as you say at the end) suggestive but not definitive.